Take-profit and stop-loss example in manual does not use the buy price to calculate the correct number
In the manual at https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/concepts/strategies/#take-profit-and-stop-loss I copied and pasted the example and noticed they do not use the buy price to calculate the stop loss and take profit.
It seems they are using the previous candle's close price, which has nothing to do with the price you bought it at.
This confuses me because if you want an accurate stop loss and take profit, you must use the price you bought the stock at in the calculation.
Is this a mistake in the documentation, or is it impossible to use the actual buy price to calculate the stop loss and take profit?
